# Save a hex String to File.hex in java

Tags: java, file, hex, decimal

I have a String which contains hex values. Now i want to write this exact string to a file with the ending .hex . How can i realize this in java?

I already tried to convert the Hex Values into ASCII and then write this string into a file.
But all Hex Values which are higher then 127(dec) can't be processed correctly.

86(hex) is transformed to ?(char), which is 3F(hex) and not 86(hex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the Answer was this:

Under Projectproperties i needed to set the Text-file-Encoding to ISO-8859-1.
Then my old procedure worked very well.

```
public static String hexToASCII(String hex){        
 if(hex.length()%2 != 0){
    System.err.println("requires EVEN number of chars");
    return null;
 }
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                
 for( int i=0; i < hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){
     String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
     int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
   sb.append((char)decimal); 
 }            
 return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take each char of your string, convert it to integer and then write values in bytes in a file. To do the opposite process, you just have to read the file into a byte array and convert each byte into a char to retrieve your string. Then I'm sure you can find some algorithm to cast your string into Hex string.

Comment: public static void WriteHexString(OutputStream name, String s) throws IOException {
  DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(name);
  int out=0;
  for(int i=0; i <= s.length()-1 ; i++){  //s.length()-1
  out = (int)s.charAt(i);
  //System.out.println(out);
  output.writeByte(out);
  }
  
  
  output.close();  
     } 
}